# Too much space between framed box and section title

Tags: spacing, framed

In my LaTeX document, I have some sections that contain normal text and other sections that contain text in a box, for which I use the `\framed` package.

When I try to increase the spacing below my section titles, I get the following problem: Now, the space between the frame box and the section title is larger than it is between normal text and the section title:

[image: Screenshot of the incorrect spacing]

This doesn't happen with the default section spacing.

Does anybody know how I get the frames to have the same top margin as normal text?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{8ex}{4ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{8ex}{4ex}

% ------------------

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
Here is text with the correct margin above the text.

\section{Second section}
\begin{framed}
  Here is framed text with too much space above the frame.  
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that when you run your MWE you get lots of complaints in the `.log` file. KOMA complains that you shouldn't use `titlesec` with KOMA (you should use KOMA's own features). `titlesec` complains about non-standard sectioning commands.

Comment: @moewe yeah, this seems to be the problem, I now got it to work with `\RedeclareSectionCommand`. Thank you!

Comment: If you solved your own question, please do not hesitate to post your solution as an answer (and accept it - after a waiting period).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As moewe pointed out, `titlesec` apparently shouldn't be used with KOMA. I got it to work correctly using the following command instead:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1.5em]{section}
```